# What is the outer track on my Ludo board for?

Tags: ludo

This is the board from a Ludo game I bought. From my previous experience with the game, I am familiar with the central cross-shaped path area, and the "HOME PATH" is the coloured bits in the center corresponding to each player. I don't remember the outside track with the green, orange and blue circles.
[image: Ludo board]

I can't find any reference to them in the rules that came with the game. Does anyone know what the track is for?

Transcribed rules below:

> **LUDO**
>
> **2 To 4 PLAYERS**
>
> **OBJECT:**
>
> Players in turn race each other around the board to be the first to get all their pieces to the "HOME Triangle".
>
> **THE PLAY:**
>
> 1. Each player takes a set of four pieces and places them on the starting square of the same colour.
> 2. Players take turns to throw the dice. The player who throws the highest number starts the game.
> 3. To the right of each player's START square is a space marked with an arrow that is the same colour as your markers. This is your ENTER space.
> 4. One must throw a six before he/she can move a piece onto the track.
> 5. Every time you throw a six (6) you get another throw and you can move any one of your pieces to the number shown on the dice.
> 6. If your piece lands on one of your opponent's piece, the opponent's piece is knocked off and returned to the starting circle.
> 7. If one of your pieces lands on a square where another of your counters is already there, this forms a block, Your block can not be passed by any one of the opponent's pieces.
> 8. If a piece is on the (*) square it cannot be knocked off.
> 9. When a piece goes all the way round the board it can enter its HOME PATH.
> 10. To land in the HOME Triangle one must throw the exact number.
>
> **The winner is the first player to get all his/her 4 pieces into the Home Triangle.**
>
> The remaining players. if they wish may continue the game to determine second and third places.

[image: Rules included with the game]

Comment: While I do not know what the outer ring is for, the same board is sold on amazon as "Creative Educational Snakes and Ladders Ludo Creative Games".

Comment: I think there is an expert variant of the game called Super Ludo which uses that track, but no details. Note that there are only three colours for the trail spots (red is missing), but Ludo can be played by four players.

Comment: Super ludo just adds abilities to the pieces, but this could be for a different variant, The manufacturer's website: https://www.creativeeducationalaids.com/product/snakes-ladders-and-ludo/ doesn't mention any additional games or variants, so it might just be vestigial